# Pandas and python datetime timestamps from CSV

Tags: python, csv, datetime, pandas

I Have a csv file of tidal data with a gap in it where the data was not collected. It looks like this:

```
    datetime,tidal_water_level
    2014-05-13 00:00:00,0.008
    2014-05-13 01:00:00,-0.283
    2014-05-13 02:00:00,-0.491
    2014-05-13 03:00:00,-0.557
    ...
```

etc

My opening gambit for loading it into a data frame is this:

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import datetime as dt

    headers = ['timestamp', 'tide_height']
    dtypes = [dt.datetime, float] 
    df = pd.read_csv('tides_clean.csv', names=headers, dtype=dtypes, header=1, parse_dates=True)
```

which I have put together from various other examples. It complains that dt.datetime is not understood.

If I remove the dtype arguments then it looks like this:

```
    df
    Out[103]: 
                    timestamp  tide_height
    0     2014-05-13 01:00:00       -0.283
    1     2014-05-13 02:00:00       -0.491
    2     2014-05-13 03:00:00       -0.557
    ...
```

How can I work with the time series data itself as a datetime type, rather than the index, please? e.g. plot time v. tide, not index v. tide

I try:
        plt.scatter(x=df.timestamp, y=df.tide_height)
and get an empty 1.0 x 1.0 square plot plus a an error thus:
        ValueError: First argument must be a sequence

My ultimate goal is to resample the data onto a different sampling frequency but this seems to be my first hurdle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to do this, and pandas will understand the datatype:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('df.csv', parse_dates = True, index_col = 0)
```

Then `df.plot()` will give you a time series plot with time on the x axis. If you want the access the index as datetime objects, you can do

```
df.index.to_pydatetime()
```

Comment: Thanks very much - I'd not understood the significance of the index_col flag and I learnt several things as a result of this answer.